# How to convert paragraph with multiple sections to json in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert following text to json. I'm not finding a way to split it based on different sections as there are multiple lines in "Installed Features " value. Please let me know a way to achieve this? I tried with regular expression but it is not working.

```
VER0010I: Copyright (c) IBM Corporation 2002, 2012; All rights reserved.
WVER0012I: VersionInfo reporter version 1.15.1.48, dated 2/8/12

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IBM WebSphere Product Installation Status Report
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Report at date and time July 8, 2020 8:08:44 AM EDT

Installation
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Product Directory        /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
Version Directory        /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties/version
DTD Directory            /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties/version/dtd
Log Directory            /var/ibm/InstallationManager/logs

Product List
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ND                       installed
IBMJAVA8                 installed

Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                  IBM WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment
Version               8.5.5.9
ID                    ND
Build Level           cf091608.05
Build Date            2/25/16
Package               com.ibm.websphere.ND.v85_8.5.5009.20160225_0435
Architecture          x86-64 (64 bit)
Installed Features    IBM 64-bit WebSphere SDK for Java
                      WebSphere Application Server Full Profile
                      EJBDeploy tool for pre-EJB 3.0 modules
                      Embeddable EJB container
                      Stand-alone thin clients and resource adapters

Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                  IBM WebSphere SDK Java Technology Edition (Optional)
Version               8.0.2.10
ID                    IBMJAVA8
Build Level           cf091608.04
Build Date            2/24/16
Package               com.ibm.websphere.IBMJAVA.v80_8.0.2010.20160224_1829
Architecture          x86-64 (64 bit)
Installed Features    IBM WebSphere SDK for Java Technology Edition 8

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
End Installation Status Report
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What have you tried exactly? Why is it not working?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors/problems have you ran into?

Comment: More importantly, what is the expected output?

Comment: if sections are different then use different code for different sections.

Comment: maybe first split to rows, every row split in two items (columns) and then check if some row has empty first column and add it to previous row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If section has multiline value then you can split to rows, and every row to columns (they have always the same length) and then you can use loop which copy rows to new list and it checks if first column is empty - if it is empty then add second column to previous row.

```
text = '''Name                  IBM WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment
Version               8.5.5.9
ID                    ND
Build Level           cf091608.05
Build Date            2/25/16
Package               com.ibm.websphere.ND.v85_8.5.5009.20160225_0435
Architecture          x86-64 (64 bit)
Installed Features    IBM 64-bit WebSphere SDK for Java
                      WebSphere Application Server Full Profile
                      EJBDeploy tool for pre-EJB 3.0 modules
                      Embeddable EJB container
                      Stand-alone thin clients and resource adapters'''

# split to rows
rows = text.split('\n')

# split to columns
rows = [[x[:22].strip(), x[22:].strip()] for x in rows]

# append to previous row
new_rows = []

for col1, col2 in rows:
    if col1:
        # copy without changes
        new_rows.append([col1, col2])
    else:
        # append to last row
        new_rows[-1][1] += '\n' + col2

# convert to dictionary and convert multiline value to list

data = {}

for col1, col2 in new_rows:
    if '\n' in col2:
        col2 = col2.split('\n')
        
    data[col1] = col2        

import json
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Result:

```
{
    "Name": "IBM WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment",
    "Version": "8.5.5.9",
    "ID": "ND",
    "Build Level": "cf091608.05",
    "Build Date": "2/25/16",
    "Package": "com.ibm.websphere.ND.v85_8.5.5009.20160225_0435",
    "Architecture": "x86-64 (64 bit)",
    "Installed Features": [
        "IBM 64-bit WebSphere SDK for Java",
        "WebSphere Application Server Full Profile",
        "EJBDeploy tool for pre-EJB 3.0 modules",
        "Embeddable EJB container",
        "Stand-alone thin clients and resource adapters"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following script parses the report as a whole.

**However, take into account that it could break, as we don't know the full format rules of the report, so given a different input, the script might have to be adjusted.**

```
def determine_line_type(line, prev_line_type):
    # Determine line type
    if line.startswith("----"):
        line_type = "separator"
    elif '    ' in line:
        if line.startswith(' '):
            line_type = "key-value-continuation-line"
        else:
            line_type = "key-value-line"
    elif not line:
        line_type = "empty"
    elif line and line[0] != ' ':
        # Line contains text from first char.
        # It's either a section header (like 'Installed Product'),
        # or just free text (like 'Report at date and time July 8, 2020 8:08:44 AM EDT')
        # We can't tell at this point, as only next line will tell (by whether it's
        # a separator or not).
        line_type = "text"
    else:
        raise ValueError(line)

    return line_type


def parse_line_types(lines):
    prev_line_type = None
    line_types = []
    for line in lines:
        line_type = determine_line_type(line, prev_line_type)
        line_types.append(line_type)
    return line_types


def parse_report(report_text):
    result = dict()

    # Initialize state
    line_parsing_started = False
    current_section_fields = dict()
    current_section_text = ""
    current_field_name = None
    current_section_header = None
    prev_line_type = None
    prev_line = None

    # Parse lines
    lines = report_text.splitlines()
    line_types = parse_line_types(lines)
    for line_idx, line in enumerate(lines):
        line_type = determine_line_type(line, prev_line_type)

        # Check if parsing should start (wait for first separator)
        if not line_parsing_started:
            if line_type == "separator":
                line_parsing_started = True
            continue

        if line_type == "separator" and prev_line_type == 'text':
            # We've ended a section, store it in result (unless it's empty, in which case it's a section
            # with no text or fields
            if current_section_fields:
                section_content = current_section_fields
            elif current_section_text:
                section_content = current_section_text

            # If there's already a section with this name, make a list of sections to store multiple
            # section with the same name
            if current_section_header in result:
                if isinstance(result[current_section_header], list):
                    result[current_section_header].append(section_content)
                else:
                    result[current_section_header] = [result[current_section_header], section_content]
            elif current_section_header is not None:
                result[current_section_header] = section_content

            # Store state of new section
            current_section_header = prev_line
            current_section_fields = dict()
            current_section_text = ""
        elif line_type == 'key-value-line':
            key_value_separator_index = line.index('    ')
            current_field_name, current_field_value = (line[:key_value_separator_index],
                                                    line[key_value_separator_index:].strip())
            current_section_fields[current_field_name] = current_field_value
        elif line_type == 'key-value-continuation-line':
            if isinstance(current_section_fields[current_field_name], str):
                current_section_fields[current_field_name] = [current_section_fields[current_field_name]]
            current_section_fields[current_field_name].append(line.strip())
        elif line_type == "text":
            is_header = line_idx < len(lines) and line_types[line_idx + 1] == 'separator'
            if not is_header:
                is_first_line_in_section_text = not current_section_text
                if not is_first_line_in_section_text:
                    current_section_text += "\n"
                current_section_text += line
        elif not line:
            continue

        prev_line_type = line_type
        prev_line = line

    return result
```

Usage:

```
CONTENT = ... # The full content of the report
import pprint
pprint.pprint(parse_report(CONTENT))
```

The above usage produces this dictionary (on which you can simply apply json.dump, if you need it as JSON):

```
{'IBM WebSphere Product Installation Status Report': 'Report at date and time July 8, 2020 8:08:44 AM EDT',
 'Installation': {'DTD Directory': '/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties/version/dtd',
                  'Log Directory': '/var/ibm/InstallationManager/logs',
                  'Product Directory': '/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer',
                  'Version Directory': '/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties/version'},
 'Installed Product': [{'Architecture': 'x86-64 (64 bit)',
                        'Build Date': '2/25/16',
                        'Build Level': 'cf091608.05',
                        'ID': 'ND',
                        'Installed Features': ['IBM 64-bit WebSphere SDK for Java',
                                               'WebSphere Application Server Full Profile',
                                               'EJBDeploy tool for pre-EJB 3.0 modules',
                                               'Embeddable EJB container',
                                               'Stand-alone thin clients and resource adapters'],
                        'Name': 'IBM WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment',
                        'Package': 'com.ibm.websphere.ND.v85_8.5.5009.20160225_0435',
                        'Version': '8.5.5.9'},
                       {'Architecture': 'x86-64 (64 bit)',
                        'Build Date': '2/24/16',
                        'Build Level': 'cf091608.04',
                        'ID': 'IBMJAVA8',
                        'Installed Features': 'IBM WebSphere SDK for Java Technology Edition 8',
                        'Name': 'IBM WebSphere SDK Java Technology Edition (Optional)',
                        'Package': 'com.ibm.websphere.IBMJAVA.v80_8.0.2010.20160224_1829',
                        'Version': '8.0.2.10'}],
 'Product List': {'IBMJAVA8': 'installed', 'ND': 'installed'}}
```

Comment: Thanks you!!...it helped me to solve this